# Security Error while trying to play a sound in Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm new to Firefox add-on development, and I have a problem while trying to play a sound in my add-on.

It's an add-on for timekeeping. Users can configure meetings settings (duration, participants... etc) through a Panel. There is a toolbar. It contains several buttons (Start, Next, Stop, Add Participant) and a Frame (to display how many participants haven't speaked yet). I change the `document.border.style` property from "green" to "red" as timers countdown.

This works fine. But I was asked to make my add-on play a sound when the `document.border.style` property turns "orange" and then "red" and I can't make it works.

I have tried several things :

1-Adding a property/attribute (I don't know which term is the right to use in that context, maybe both, anyway) to my TimeKeeper variable for each sound that has to be played. Meaning in my code :

```
orangeBorderStyle: new Audio(relativePathToMyMp3orWAVFile),
redBorderStyle: new Audio(relativePathToMyMp3orWAVFile),
```

and then calling their play() method in the countdown() method. But it didn't work.

2-Currently, I'm trying to play the sounds from HTML5 audio tags I added to the frame.url HTML file. But it doesn't work either.

The HTML file looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Frame</title>
</head>
  <body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/Frame_script.js"></script>
    Speakers Left : <input id="speakers" size="4" value="" disabled />
    <audio id="orangeSound" src="Audio/orangeBorderSoundTest.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <audio id="redSound" src="Audio/redBorderSoundTest.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
            Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
 </body>
</html>
```

In Frame_script.js I have :

```
window.addEventListener("message", reactToMessages, false);


var orangeBorderSound=document.getElementById("orangeSound");
var redBorderSound=document.getElementById("redSound");
//console.log(orangeBorderSound);

function reactToMessages(e){
    if(isNaN(e.data)==false){
    displaySpeakersLeft(e);
    }

if(e.data=="orangeBorderSound")
{
    document.getElementById("orangeSound").play();
    //console.log("Je joue le son Orange.");
} else if(e.data=="redBorderSound")
{
    document.getElementById("redSound").play();
    //console.log("Je joue le son Rouge.");
}
}

function displaySpeakersLeft(e){
    document.getElementById("speakers").value=e.data;
}
```

and in Timers.js I have the following calls :

```
Frame.get().postMessage("orangeBorderSound", Frame.get().url);
Frame.get().postMessage("redBorderSound", Frame.get().url);
```

Both calls trigger the right code (when the console.log() are commented out, they are displayed correctly) but there is no sound in the end.

Please, note that the `value` of the input tag with ID "speakers" is correctly displayed in my add-on so it seems that the document.getElementById() methods returns the right thing, and that it is the right way to do things with an input tag. Meaning, the paths are the right ones.  I can't see why it would be different with audio tags.

So here comes my question : I now see the error "Security Error: Content at moz-nullprincipal:... may not load or link to resource..." (the  resource path given seems to be the right one for each audio file) in the Error Console.

Is this really a security issue ? Or would I have little to change to make my code works ? What would you do ?

Any explanation or suggestion would be appreciated. I really don't see what's wrong with what I've done. Why would it cause security problems ?

Please, note that I've tried to use the audio tags method in a new add-on with just a Play button in the Panel and nothing else, but this time with the audio tags in the Panel contentURL HTML file, calling the play() method in the contentScriptFile and it worked.

No security error this time.

But I suppose I can't accept such a solution in my timekeeping add-on since I need to synchronize the call of the play() method with the change of the border style and that there is no Play button this time. It does not correspond to what I want to obtain. It was just for testing purpose.

Timers.js which is in my lib directory cannot interact with the Panel contentScriptFile which is in the data directory, so it couldn't be a solution even if the sounds were correctly loaded and ready to be played.

What do I get wrong ?

Comment: My problem remains unsolved. Feel free to ask for more informations if you think it's necessary. I don't know how to deal with the Security Error because I have no idea what might cause it.